# If SpriteBatch.Draw's SourceRectangle is null does a rectangle still get created?

Tags: xna, c#

If you use the following `SpriteBatch.Draw` overload, does a `Rectangle` get created for the texture?

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, textureRectangle, null, Color.White, 0f, textureOrigin, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
```

If so how would you access the `Rectangle`?

Comment: This isn't very clear.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Jon I'm trying to understand if a Rectangle is created from the SourceRectangle that is used or does one need to be applied.
If one is created how would you use the new Rectangle in say collision detection?

Comment: The rectangle you are specifying to extract an image from a spritesheet has nothing to do with the rectangle you would use for hit detection.  You will need to create a different rectangle for that.  The X,Y coordinates of your destination rectangle starts from 0,0 of the source image.  It is not relative to your game world at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an equivelent rectangle like so:

```
Rectangle sourceRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, texture.Width, texture.Height);
```

Or simply use `texture.Bounds`.

Note that there's no GC overhead to creating a `Rectangle` as it is a value type (`struct`), and the construction cost is negligible (relatively). So you don't need to worry about the cost of creating your own, or any internal cost inside `SpriteBatch`.

Answer (score 1):

The SourceRectangle is used to extract only parts of a texture.  This is useful when dealing with spritesheets.

By using null you are saying you want to draw the whole texture.

Let's say you wanted to only draw the tree from this texture. If each tile were 16 by 16 pixels you would enter.

[image: Desciption Pict]

```
spriteBatch.Draw(myTilesheet, // The Texture2D
                 new Rectangle(10, 10, 16,16), // This rectangle positions the texture on the screen and scales it can also be a Vector2
                 new Rectangle(0, 80, 16,16), // This describes where to find the tree tile
                 Color.White, 
                 0f,  
                 Vector2.Zero,
                 SpriteEffects.None,
                 1f);
```

Comment: That makes sense. So would you then need to apply a Rectangle to the 16x16 texture you just drew or would one be created by using the source Rectangle?

Comment: Just start a new project called Testing and throw this code into the draw method.  Add the texture I provided, don't forget spriteBatch.Begin()/.End() and play with the numbers in the two rectangles.